# Save dialog prompt for PDF instead of saving to hardcoded path

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, itext

I have successfully implemented the iTextSharp.text.pdf to populate a PDF template file we have setup. Currently that file is being save automatically to a specific folder on local machine...but we don't want that, we want the populated PDF to be saved by the user to the folder of their choice on their pc. We do not want to keep any of these files on the server once this application gets published.

the below code creates the hardcoded file path and it is populated, but the portion at the bottom that prompts the user to save the file, creates a pdf with the file name format we want, but the file is always 20k and wont open. How can I change the below code to not actually create the file on the server, but to create it to the users pc when they chose to save it?

```
using (FileStream outfile = new FileStream(outputfile, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdftemplate);
                    PdfStamper stm = new PdfStamper(rdr, outfile);
                    AcroFields fields = stm.AcroFields;

                    foreach (var de in rdr.AcroFields.Fields)
                    {                                                        
                        if (de.Key == "Date")
                        {
                            fields.SetField("Date", dt.Rows[0]["Form Date"].ToString());
                        }
                        if (de.Key == "Project Name")
                        {
                            fields.SetField("Project Name", dt.Rows[0]["Project Name"].ToString());
                        }
                        if (de.Key == "Contract No")
                        {
                            fields.SetField("Contract No", dt.Rows[0]["Contract Number"].ToString());
                        }

                    }

                    stm.Close();
                    rdr.Close();

                    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + newFile);
                    Response.Write(outfile);
                    Response.End();
                }
```

Comment: You can try to read the file contents into a `byte[]` array and wrap that array with a `MemoryStream` stream. Then use that `MemoryStream` stream instead of `FileStream` you are using now (so fill it in and write to the `Response` object). You can also try to reset the stream to restore its initial position just before writing it to the `Response` stream.

Comment: So instead of using FileStream use MemoryStream?

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure if it'll solve the issue, but it may help. As I understand, You asked about two issues: 1. How to not overwrite template PDF file that is on server. 2. How to allow users to download the updated file correctly. Is this correct? Using `MemoryStream` should help in 1. and may help with 2.

Comment: Well for the pdf portion, it needed the template file to use to populate and then a output file to create with the populated values.. , it would be nice that instead of providing a output file that the output is pushed to the user to download instead of being saved directly to our server. Since the user can request the form as many times as they want, we don't want to manage that, if you as the user select a report to view, then you are prompted to open the form or save it(all of which need to happen on the users pc) not on our server. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Writing bytes of the file after it's filled in (or a stream that contains those bytes) to the `Response` stream may then work this way. This will send filled in file directly to the user and it will not be saved on the server. However, please note that the whole filling in process will be triggered each time when a user asks for the file if there is no caching mechanism implemented.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem with your code is that you are using `filestream` which is causing the pdf to be saved to your server.  Using `memorystream` should fix this.  Try something like this and see if it helps.

```
Using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfReader rdr = new PdfReader(pdftemplate);
    PdfStamper stm = new PdfStamper(rdr, ms);
    AcroFields fields = stm.AcroFields;

    foreach (var de in rdr.AcroFields.Fields)
    {
        if (de.Key == "Date")
        { fields.SetField("Date", dt.Rows[0]["Form Date"].ToString()); }

        if (de.Key == "Project Name")
        { fields.SetField("Project Name", dt.Rows[0]["Project Name"].ToString()); }

        if (de.Key == "Contract No")
        { fields.SetField("Contract No", dt.Rows[0]["Contract Number"].ToString()); }
    }

    stm.Close();
    rdr.Close();

    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=MyFile.pdf"); 
    //To display pdf in the browser window instead of saving, change attachment to inline
    Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray());
    Response.End();
}
```

By using `MemoryStream` along with html headers, you should get a prompt to save the file.